# Stop refreshing with ajax , javascript , php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, forms

My code looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
    var queryString = "?age=" + age;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-example.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
</script>

<form name='myForm'>
Max Age: <input type='text' id='age' /> <br />
<input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction()' value='Query MySQL' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I used Ajax to stop redirection but it is still refreshing, how can I stop it?

Comment: That code should not cause a page refresh.

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail - what is happening ?? and what you expect to happen ??

Comment: i am having a button after scroling , when i click it it goes to top like refreshing , help !! , i want to change simple text of button and submit like above

Comment: hey i got it , it's navigating to top , not refreshing ..  hElp how to sttop it at same place .. plzz

Answer (score 4):

You could try adding return false;

```
<input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction();return false' value='Query MySQL' />
```

Comment: I have been trying many things as suggested in many other posts but yours is the only one working, thank you. I can't believe people didn't give you upvotes!

Answer (score 1):

Well that codes doesn't refreshing for me but still i'm not good with ajax did you checked error console or try jQuery you can do it easily with it

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function ajaxFunction(){
    var age = $("#age").val();
    $.get("ajax-example.php",{"age":age},function(r){ /*Do something with response*/ });
}
</script>
Max Age: <input type='text' id='age' /> <br />
<input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction()' value='Query MySQL' />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am having a button after scroling , when i click it it goes to top like refreshing , help !! , i want to change simple text of button and submit like above

Comment: which browser you're using ??? its not scrolling to top in my browser or you've any other code which is making this problem